# cannot load such file -- chef/encrypted_data_bag_item

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I have a vagrant file that actually has the line

```
require 'chef/encrypted_data_bag_item'
```

and when i do a `bundle exec vagrant_tests` it gives me the following error

```
cannot load such file -- chef/encrypted_data_bag_item
```

when i do a `gem list --local i have chef (10.26.0)` installed. I am not sure what could be the problem .

Comment: I don't think that is the proper way of adding the encrypted data bag, why are your requiring it?  It should be opened like File.read() if you need to use it.

Comment: What's the full Vagrantfile? What's the rest of the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vagrant plugin install chef` seems to fix the issue